# How to get the tabController from subview in tabs

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, tabbar

I have a Class: myTabController, in this class I have a UITabBarController, which has 4 subviews in this UITabBarController.

Now I am in my first subview, say it's tab1, 
I can call self.parentViewController to get the UITabBarController, and this UITabBarController is owned by myTabController, but How can I get myTabController then? Cause I want to access some data in myTabController.

Thanks Ahead,
Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your wording I am assuming that you have not subclassed UITabBarController.  I would suggest having a property on all four view controllers, something like `theTabController`, which points to an instance of your class.  Declare this property like this (in the subviews):

```
@class myTabController;
...
@interface MySubview : UIView {
    ...
    myTabController * theTabController;
    ...
}
...
@property (nonatomic, assign) myTabController * theTabController;
```

Then, in each subview's implementation, add a synthesize statement.  It's also a good idea to import the header of `myTabController` in the `.m`, even though we have an `@class` in the subview's header.  I used an `@class` to prevent circular imports.

```
#import "myTabController."
...
@implementation MySubview
@synthesize theTabController;
...
@end
```

From `myTabController`, you need to set this property on each subview like this:

```
subview1.theTabController = self;
subview2.theTabController = self;
...
subviewx.theTabController = self;
```

Finally, use the `theTabController` property sub inside each subview with `self.theTabController`.

I also have to point out: it's never good to have a class name that starts with a lower case letter.  `myTabController` should really be `MyTabController`.

Comment: Thanx, but the myTabController I mean is an object of the MyTabController class it's like: MyTabController * myTabController; Whatever, u helped me out! and u r 14!!?? seriously?it makes me feel shame! Thanx though!